# Convert object string to object(class) in C# using Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, listbox, converters

Here I am going to tell you what I am working on with and after that there comes my question. I want to tell you guys what I am working on.. so you guys can understand my problem better.

Thanks in advance,

I am working on a project. This app is a grocery calculator. I got a class called Artikel. This class is the base class of my other derived classes like (vegetables, drinks, warmfood.. etc).

I got a combobox filled with data from my database. What I want to do is to add the price of each product to the "total cost cart". my base class looks like this:

```
class Artikel
{
    // properties
    private string naam;
    private double prijs;
    private string winkel;

    // properties
    public string Naam
    {
        get { return naam; }
        set { naam = value; }
    }

    public double Prijs
    {
        get { return prijs; }
        set { prijs = value; }
    }

    public string Winkel
    {
        get { return winkel; }
        set { winkel = value; }
    }

    // constructor
    public Artikel(string naam, double prijs, string winkel)
    {
        this.Naam = naam;
        this.Prijs = prijs;
        this.Winkel = winkel;
    }

    // methods
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string info = "€ " + Prijs;
        return info;
    }
```

From my main form I use this code to add it to my combobox:

```
    foreach(var g in database.GetGroenteInfo())
    {
        cbGroentenLidl.Items.Add(g.Naam);
    }
```

When the combobox is full with "vegetable" data I can select an item. from here I can add the selected item to my "lbLidlKosten" with this code:

```
lbLidlKosten.Items.Add(cbGroentenLidl.SelectedItem);
```

**Now that my data is right where I want it.. here is the problem.** Now I want to add the price from each product that I add to the listbox... to my label. So basicly the more product I add to the "lbLidlKosten" the more my costs will grow in the label.text. I hope you know what I mean.

I tried the following to get that one working:

```
    artikelList = database.GetGroenteInfo();

    //foreach (Artikel a in artikelList)
    //{
    //    label2.Text = Convert.ToString(a.Prijs);
    //    label2.Text = cbGroentenLidl.SelectedItem;
    //}

    //foreach (Artikel a in lbLidlKosten.Items)
    //{
    //    label2.Text = a.Prijs.ToString();
    //}

    //Artikel artikel = (Artikel)cbGroentenLidl.SelectedItem;
    //label2.Text = artikel.Prijs.ToString();

    foreach (Artikel a in lbLidlKosten.Items)
    {
        label2.Text = Convert.ToString(a.Prijs);
    }
```

All these solutions won't work. Because I am getting the error: 
"Cannot convert object string to object Artikel".

Does anyone has a clue? It could be simple.. but I cannot find it and I am stuck for the last 3 days.

With kind regards

Comment: maybe it could work. but the place where it all goes fail is in the foreach. when it tries to loop in the foreach with each artikel in my list or combobox.. I get the error "cannot convert object string to object Artikel(class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In here:

```
foreach(var g in database.GetGroenteInfo())
{
    cbGroentenLidl.Items.Add(g.Naam);
}
```

You're adding the name to the combo box, rather than the item itself.
Perhaps you can try binding the item collection to the combo box datasource, like so:

```
cbGroentenLidl.DataSource = database.GetGroenteInfo().ToList();
cbGroentenLidl.DisplayMember = "Naam";
```

Then when you add to the listbox, you will have the object, rather than just the name.

Comment: Hey! This is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't added the object to the combobox. Thanks alot. I mark your awnser as the right given one. cheers

Answer (score 1):

You're not incrementing the value, either. You could try this:

```
double prijs = 0;
foreach (Artikel a in lbLidlKosten.Items)
{
    prijs += a.Prijs;
}
label2.Text = Convert.ToString(prijis);
```

If the last line doesn't work, try this:

```
label2.Text = "" + prijs;
```

Comment: I wasn't that far with my app. But I also want to thank you for your awnser, because now my total application is finished. cheers for that!